# valid variable capture from lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference, c++11

I'm wondering if the following style of capture by reference is valid:

```
struct Foo {
 Foo( boost::function<void()> v);

 int get() const;
};

int main() {
 Foo instance( [&]() -> void { int value = instance.get(); .... } );
```

As you see, i'm capturing a reference to an object being constructed when the lambda is passed. It would seem that if the lambda is called before the constructor fully executes you are accessing a partially constructed object and you get all the danger that represents.

However, is this allowed? it would seem that as long as you make sure you understand when the lambda can be called you should be fine

Comment: What does the constructor of Foo do with v?

Comment: it might store it for later invocation. Presumably after construction. It is understood that calling it before being fully constructed would be a bug, or risky at the very least

Comment: It just gets a compile error: "`instance` is not defined" from the latest MSVC and Intel C++ compiler. So, the answer is clear: this is not allowed. Alternatively, you may pass `Foo*` as an argument in the lambda, and pass `this` when the lambda is called.

Comment: @minjang: it compiles fine on my gcc 4.5.2 with `std::function`

Comment: I'm pretty sure gcc is wrong, that shouldn't compile. The variable's scope doesn't begin until after the declaration.

Comment: Upon further examination of the C++ grammar I see that the declarator ends before the parentheses, so MSVC's parse is wrong and GCC's is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda is not executed until you execute it by writing `v()` in the `Foo` constructor. And if you do that, then it is same as if you call the function `get()` directly from the constructor, which is alright, **if** `get` is not a `virtual` function and you have implemented `get` in such way that it can be called from the constructor as well. For example, if you do this:

- [Online demo](http://www.ideone.com/6OFEH)

In this, the implementation of `get` doesn't require the object to be fully constructed.

Also, although it is not related to your question, but still make a note that since you are using C++11 (as implied by the usage of lambda), why don't you use `std::function` instead of `boost::function` (like I did in my [demo](http://www.ideone.com/6OFEH))? If your compiler supports lambda, it will support `std::function` as well, for it's implementation is very trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If the lambda function object is stored and not called until the object is fully constructed, then there is no problem. As elsewhere in C++, it is made possible to write code that has undefined behaviour, in order to make it more convenient to take advantage of a subset of cases where the behaviour is defined.